# Gazebo window can not be maximized in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When launching gazebo, there are some important controls (clock) that can not be seen in the default window configuration. When I try to get the window maximized, the button and the contextual menu of the window are disabled, and then is impossible to access the clock control tool.

After testing, I found that there are two alternatives to get the window maximized, the first is double-clicking the window title bar, the second is using the full-screen gazebo alternative, when the window is in full-screen mode the Maximize button appears, and can be clicked, when returning to default view (non full screen), the windows remains maximized.

It could be great to have a natural way to see the time controls, instead of having to use tricks to get it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2951/gazebo-window-can-not-be-maximized-in-ubuntu-12.04/) by [oscar.st](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/356/oscar.st/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-05-23**:
use two screens would be a way to overcome

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2013-05-24**:
What is your screen resolution?

**Comment by [oscar.st](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/356/oscar.st/) on 2013-06-05**:
My screen resolution is 1366x768, and use two screens is not a solution.

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-06-06**:
it is. At least that's how I managed to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is an issue to track this problem:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/725/default-gui-window-size-is-too-big

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0